# Library errors running ansible on azure vm

Tags: azure, ansible

Module not loaded error running ansible on Azure.

Trying to install ansible on Azure and run some test code

Trying to test some deployment installing ansible on an Azure VM. 
--installed following packages in the VM 
--Azure specific 
--install packages for azure python SDK modules

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip
```

--install ansible packeges

```
sudo pip install ansible[azure]
sudo pip install msrestazure
sudo pip install msrest
```

When trying creating a resource group, get an error with library not loaded error

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create resource group
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
        name: ansible-rg
        location: centralus
      register: rg
    - debug:
        var: rg
```

Getting the error,

> TASK [Create resource group]
>   ************************************************************************************************************* An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named
>   typing fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "Failed to import the required Python library (msrestazure) on
>   's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and
>   install in the appropriate location"}
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> Create the resource group

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you use the python2 and execute the command `sudo pip install` then it will install the packages in the path /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. But if you change something of the environment and you do not know, there will be some errors and you also do not know.

So I will suggest you use the virtual environment, it will not affect your real environment. So follow the steps here:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev python-pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo mkdir ansible
sudo virtualenv ansible
cd ansible
source bin/activate
```

Now the virtual environment is ready and you can install the ansible in it.

```
sudo pip install ansible[azure]
```

Then create the credentials file in the path ~/.azure/ with your service principal. And when you install the `ansible[azure]`, the packages `msrest` and `msrestazure` is already installed. So you do not need to install them again. Then you can try to create the resource group again.

Comment: I ended up creating an ansible script to install airflow.

Comment: #This script is going to install Python3-pip and Ansible
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt -y update
sudo apt -y install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

#Installing Ansible
sudo pip3 install ansible
sudo easy_install -U cffi
sudo easy_install -U cryptography

Comment: uninstalling the ansible installed with pip, replace it with pip3 with above changes